# Execute SQL dump in Yii

Tags: sql, yii, dump

I know I can execute (actually, creating it, not yet executed) custom SQL in Yii using:

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;   // assuming you have configured a "db" connection
// If not, you may explicitly create a connection:
// $connection=new CDbConnection($dsn,$username,$password);
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
// if needed, the SQL statement may be updated as follows:
// $command->text=$newSQL;
```

**Question**: How can I execute a sql dump? i.e.

```
`$dump = file_get_contents('products.sql');`
```

**Note**: This dump has **multiple** commands - AFAIK createCommand works for **single** command - Am I wrong?

**Note 2**: I cannot break queries by ';' character (SQL delimiter) since such character is widely used among product data, so I have to execute the dump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You CAN execute multiple commands with `createCommand()`

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tst (
  f varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE = INNODB
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

PHP:

```
...
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO tst SET f='test1'; INSERT INTO tst SET f='test2';")->execute();
...
```

MySQL:

```
mysql> select * from tst;
+-------+
| f     |
+-------+
| test1 |
| test2 |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So if your products.sql contains valid SQL this should work:

```
$sql = file_get_contents('products.sql');
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Comment: :D tested it. when posted the question i was seeking for a good approach since I did not reach that part yet.

Comment: ALTHOUGHT actually, for 1.1.14, the line would be: `Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();`. I edited like that to make it work.